# Products not showing

Tags: products, category-products, product-urls

can you help with this? Setting up site at http://bulklolliesnz.co.nz/store/

Imported products which are showing in categories and search but when clicking product link they're not there. Flushed cache, re-indexed.

Comment: System log shows "ERR (3): Warning: imagecopymerge() expects parameter 9 to be long"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are getting the blank page on product view page. I checked the console and it shows internal server error while loading the product page. This might issue you are talking about.
You can try following this method for the internal server error.

http://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. The post didn't solve it but lead me down the right path - was an extension problem.